# Captured counter in C# lambdas

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to count some filtered data in List of objects (TSource), while processing it in result list (TResult). My method looks like:

```
int ratedUsersCount = 0;
return sourceList.
.GroupBy(x => x.UserId)
.Select(u => {
    var count = u.Count();
    if (count >= 10) ratedUsersCount ++;
    return new ... //some new object with calculations
    }
)
.OrderByDescending(_ => some field)
.ThenByDescending(_ => some other field)
.Take(20)
.Select((u, i) => {
                      u.Index = i + 1;
                      u.Rating = i / ratedUsersCount ;
                      return u;
                  };
);
```

So, does the variable ratedUsersCount use incorrectly?
How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Have you tried it? What behavior does this give you?

Comment: The counter will not be incremented until you iterate the query.  On a side note it's generally bad practice to write Linq queries with side effects.

Comment: ratedUsersCount has a risk to stay 0 and you have a potential division by zero exception..

Comment: thanks! Yes, I tried it, it's working good and unit tests prove it, but I want to find more elegant solution and reduce the side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting your code up, it will become much cleaner, easier to understand, and won't produce side effects from within LINQ.

```
var groupedUsers = sourceUsers.GroupBy(x => x.UserId);
var minimumCount = 10;
var ratedUserCount = grouperUsers.Count(x => x.Take(minimumCount + 1).Count() >= minimumCount);
var intermediateUsers = groupedUsers.Select(x => new { /* ... */ });
var filteredUsers = intermediateUsers.OrderByDescending(/* ... */).ThenByDescending(/* ... */).Take(20);
var finalUsers = filteredUsers.Select(/* ... */);
```

Note that this may be a little slower, since `grouperUsers.Count(x => x.Count() >= 10)` will enumerate the IEnumerable in order to apply the counting function.

Comment: Using `Take(n+1)` before applying a comparison against `Count()` is a nice way to minimise the overhead of counting.

Comment: @TheInnerLight Thanks, didn't think of that. That is actually a pretty smart way to optimize counting IEnumerable elements in some cases, I'll be using that a lot.